# Some software that goes over the taskbar goes below my display

Tags: lubuntu

I've been using a very ruined taskbar on Lubuntu since i decided to try and change it's settings, i didn't mind how it was but i just realized that it ruined something deeper in my system because when i try to play a video on fullscreen the video is cut a few pixels on the lower part of its window, same with video-games.

How can i fix this?

Also it could be good if someone helped to just make the taskbar go back to normal, right now i can't find a way to display the apps completely.

Comment: You haven't told us what release of Lubuntu you mean, but the Lubuntu manual provides some detail on configuration of the LXQt panel - https://manual.lubuntu.me/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html  (you may be using LXDE instead of the modern LXQt, but we cannot know without being told so may not apply to your release)

Comment: I'm on Lubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: I haven't tested this, but assuming your issue is with lxpanel config (you mention taskbar; I'm assuming you mean your panel which is `lxpanel` for LXDE found in Lubuntu 18.04), backup your panel config somewhere beforehand. Then you could copy (`cp`) /etc/xdg/lxpanel/default/panels/panel over your current config (me I'd also `diff` to compare etc first with your existing ~/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels/panel hoping to see what's wrong & what you changed...).  Assuming you `sudo cp -pv` to copy to your directory; you'll need to `chown` (change ownership) to you before trying to login.